# limaçon in complex plane defined by $u^2+u, |u|=1$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I graphed the function $f(u) = u^2 + u$, where $f$ is from $\mathbb{C}$ to  $\mathbb{C}$. When I restricted my attention to $|u| = 1$, I got the following graph:

! [$u^2 + u$, restricted to $|u|=1$. Here point $C$ represents $u$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18b9w.png)

This looks like a limaçon, and it should be a limaçon. I am having trouble proving this though, so can I have some help?

I have tried $\operatorname{cis} \theta$ form, and gotten $\displaystyle \left( 2\cos \frac{3 \theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2} + 1 \right) + i\left( 2\sin \frac{3\theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2} \right)$ as $\theta$ varies. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(u)=u^2+u=x+iy$ and $u=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ then you get
$$
x=\cos\theta+\cos2\theta,\quad
y=\sin\theta+\sin2\theta,
$$
which is precisely the [parametric equation of a limaçon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on#Equations) with $b={a\over2}=1$, but translated by $1$ along the $x$-axis.